# socket.io.js not found on production instance

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, nginx, socket.io

First of all, yes I know there are many related question on SO for similar problem. I have gone through almost all of them before asking.

I have a very strange issue where, socket.io.js file is not served by server on production instance.

Exactly same code works on my development instance. The only difference between development annd Production instance is that, produciton instance runs using nginx proxy but I do not think that should be the problem.

When I am trying to access https://my-host-name.com/socket.io/socket.io.js

I get Error "404 Not Found"

Nginx log gives this error:

> 2017/08/17 12:01:28 [error] 30437#0: *2298619 open()
>   "/data/api/current/socket.io/socket.io.js" failed (2: No such file or
>   directory), client: 10.xxx.x.xx, server: , request: "GET
>   /socket.io/socket.io.js HTTP/1.1", host: ""

I am completely clueless whats going wrong here. Can any one please help me?

Here is my socket confiiguration on app.js file:

```
var server = https.createServer(app.get("httpsOptions"), app);
var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = socket.listen(server);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    logger.info("Starting the express app...");
    logger.info("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
require('./routes/sockets/base')(io); // separating the socket.io related code in separate file
```

I can see my node_modules already has socket.io, socket.io-adaptor, socket.io-client and socket.io-parser

Comment: You need the request for socket.io.js to get through NGINX to your express server (rather than NGINX trying to server it directly) and you need the path with it gets to your express server to be `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.  This appears to be an NGINX config problem and it looks like there's probably some sort of multi-tennant NGINX configuration that is adding `/data/api/current` onto the path too.

Comment: I tried to see the nginx conf, and added following line there:

alias /socket.io/{ alias /data/api/current/node/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/}

Now I can see the socket.io.js file served through this link:https://my-host-name.com/socket.io/socket.io.js

But all polling is failing with 403 forbidden error:

Here are nginx log: directory index of "/data/api/current/node/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist//" is forbidden,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`The only difference between development annd Production instance is that, produciton instance runs using nginx proxy but I do not think that should be the problem.` That is a very big assumption and a wrong one too.

You should set the development environment with a nginx proxy and then move to production. All the static files needs to be accessible to the `nginx` container so it can sever those static files and they don't go to your NodeJS code

Also you would need below directives in your nginx config

```
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_http_version 1.1;
```

See this for more details https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/

Comment: OK..so now I added above lines to my nginx, and here is how it looks like:
https://pastebin.com/raw/FJAm6fDT

But now I am getting error:

WebSocket connection to 'wss:/my-host-name/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=Ni1NmPNYgC8JuYHvAADa' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

I think I am very close now, but not sure what is causing this issue

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/eumXXN37

I see timeout in nginx log, and multiple User connected message in node js log.

Comment: Paste your complete nginx config

Comment: Give me 5 mins.. Currently I am afk.. Will reply soon

Comment: Is all of this running on localhost or inside docker? Also use `telnet localhost 5002` and see if that works?

Comment: all running on localhost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152254/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-undefined).